# Android: How to send SMS to email account

Tags: android, sms

The stock Android text messaging app allows you to send SMS to an email account instead of a phone number. How is this done? I tried the following code and it failed.

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage("myaccount@gmail.com", null, textMsg, sentPI, null);
```

This other question seems to be related [How to send SMS message reply to email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388950/how-to-send-sms-message-reply-to-email-address)

... but the accepted answer says

> Each cell carrier has a specific SMS number that you can send a text message to in a certain format. This is called a "SMS Gateway".

I want to send to my gmail account, not to AT&T.

Sorry, seems I misread the answer. Looks like my carrier (AT&T) will send the email for me. What puzzles me is how an app could work for different carriers?